# How to setup python.logging format using f-string style

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7, f-string, python-logging

I'm writing an app using python 3.7 and want to use only **f-strings** in it.

I'm using python logging module in order to log my application correctly, and I want to use a specific format but the documentation (and the web) only example how to change the format using %-strings.
I was wondering whether there is an option to set the logger format using f-strings

```py
LOG_FORAMT = ('%(levelname)s -10s %(asctime)s -10s %(message)s') # Known example

f-LOG_FORMAT = (f'{logger.levelname} -10s') # Something like that?
```

Comment: Set the format like that, then  just use fstrings in your message: `logger.error(f"bad var: {var}")`. So, *in practice*, you dont have to deal with weird format strings past your log setup.

Comment: I have no problems with using f-strings in logging messages (`logger.error() / logger.info() / etc...`), I was just wondering whether there is an option to use f-string format in the log formatter..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can initialize `logging.Formatter` with argument `style` set to `"{"`.

**Example**

```py
formatter = logging.Formatter("{processName:<12} {message} ({filename}:{lineno})", style="{")
```

Available options for style are [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter).

After this attach the formatter to a handler and add the handler to your desired logger(s).

If you are using `logging.basicConfig` you can set it with the following way:

```py
logging.basicConfig(format="{processName:<12} {message} ({filename}:{lineno})", style="{")
```